# Backup/Migrate all fonts from 11.10 to 12.04 (all locations)

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, backup, fonts

I don't know whether this is correct, but I seem to recall that there are multiple places to store fonts, especially with true type stuff, and multiple ways to install them (some I double click, some I copy to folders, etc.).

I don't recall where I would have put mine, or how I would have installed, (did I accidentally sudo install some, but not others?  Maybe), so I'm hoping someone can give me a recipe for where I should copy /all/ old 11.10 fonts from, and where I should copy them to on my 12.04 system---including anything I need to be mindful of with permissions, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'/usr/share/fonts'  will be your system wide fonts.

'~/.fonts'  should be all your user only fonts. (per user of course)

Comment: I know under /usr/share/fonts, there will be your 'different type of fonts' folders.  I'm not sure about the user installed.